# League of legends folder seems too big

Tags: league-of-legends

So my league of legends folder is almost 14 gb right now (13.75gb) and yet my pbe is less than 4gb what is going.. what files are taking up so much space and what can I delete so my folder is relatively clean and not wasting 14gb of my hard drive i just deleted all my log files and even after the 800mb purge my game folder is 13.75 Gb large which in my opinion is very crazy. How can I clean up my riot folder?
lolpbe
[image]

lol main
[image]

Comment: Do you have screenshots or recordings? I have 8100 files taking 3.64GB...

Comment: Mine was over 8 GB. Each server contributes 800 GB, and archived files can be large as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of that is in the '/RADS/projects' folder which is filled with old files (older versions) just in case Riot decides to rollback a patch. There are two ways you can free up some space:

**Safer** (recommended):
Uninstall league of legends, delete all files and do a fresh install. It should come back to 5-6 gb.

**Riskier** (might cause an unexpected error):
Delete the following

/lol_game_client_en_gb

/lol_game_client_de_de

/lol_game_client_en_us

Althought this might still leave some lingering unused data in the other folders.

Comment: Also /lol_game_client/filearchives
This folder can grow to be over 3 GB.
As long as you don't play on those servers, the client will not need any of the files.

Comment: Never mind. Don't delete filearchives, it's really necessary!

Comment: I deleted everything in `/RADS/projects`. The Lol folder is down to 110Mb doing that. Then I launched the LolClient.exe, it went in repair mode for a rather long time with high internet usage. Now the game is playable (the directory weight 6Gb) and I still have my personal configuration files. I wonder why Riot does not remove everying starting from the antepenultimate release themself properly in local. I guess they don't mind having high bandwith usage on their servers, this feature is nigthmarish to implement, or more probably they don't mind taking a lot of space on their user's computer.